# select all textarea which does NOT have a certain class in Jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have several textareas like:

```
<asp:textbox class="input ThisIsRussia" ..... />
<asp:textbox class="input" ..... />
<asp:textbox class="input ThisIsSparta" ..... />
<asp:textbox class="input" ..... />
```

Now, I have to select all the textarea / textbox which does not have the class "ThisIsSparta", how do I do it?

I was checking the Jquery selectors website and it said I have to uses

```
[name!=value]
```

for this purpose, but when I did this:

```
$('textarea[class!=ThisIsSparta]').SlideUp();
```

it was affecting my spartan textarea too!
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('textarea').not('.ThisIsSparta');
```

Comment: $('textarea[class=ThisIsSparta]') resolves all textarea-elements that have exactly ThisIsSparta in their class attribute, input's with class 'input ThisIsSparta' will not be resolved. However $('textarea.ThisIsSparta') works like selecting a CSS element. If that class exists for the element it is selected. Another possibility is to use: $('textarea:not(.ThisIsSparta)').

Comment: Hi, yea, i think I understand now.. I realized that it was not working because of a small mistake i did.. thanks, its all fine now :)